# AD groups authentication doesn't work at the console of SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, sql-authentication

I come up with this. A Domain admin windows user is able to login to a SQL Server 2017 instance from any client computer, but it can not login from the console of the server. TCP/IP and Shared memory protocols are enabled and the "Domain admins" group is added as well as a sysadmin.

In order to login from the console I ended up adding the specific domain admin user to workaround the problem at the console but why the same windows user can login from outside the server but it can not do that at the console through AD groups?

Comment: What error is the user getting? Also, can you elaborate on "console" are you using SQLCMD, PowerShell's SqlServer module, or another command-line tool for accessing SQL Server locally on the server?

Comment: Try running SSMS as administrator. When group membership involves groups that are local admin, UAC settings can work in surprising ways.

Comment: Hi @AndyD. Running SSMS at the physical server the error that comes up is "login failed".

Comment: I'll give it a try @AMtwo, thank you